# Opening software keyboard on Android Flash 10.1

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm developing a mobile Flash application (not an AIR app) running in the browser. According to Adobe:

> Flash Player 10.1 provides support for
>   use of native device virtual keyboards
>   with TextField support if no physical
>   keyboard is detected. A virtual
>   keyboard is automatically raised and
>   lowered in response to focus changes
>   on text fields when editing text on
>   mobile devices supporting a virtual
>   keyboard to enable unobstructed and
>   intuitive text editing. The focused
>   text field is centered in the visible
>   region of the page and appropriately
>   zoomed/scrolled to ensure it is not
>   obscured by the virtual keyboard. Upon
>   screen rotation, incoming calls, or
>   other system events, any already
>   existing text input is retained. The
>   virtual keyboard works with TextField
>   but does not currently work with the
>   Text Layout Framework or other Flash
>   Text Engine text.

I'm listening for a tap event (which works) that sets `stage.focus = input;` which also is working. However, the virtual keyboard is not triggered.

I am testing on an HTC Evo.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a hidden TextField. Then dispatch an even to it. Maybe the internal Flash Player is listening to a event of the TextField(I doubt it but it is worth a try). You could also force the Flash Player to get focus on a textfield.

`dispatchEvent(new FocusEvent(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, true, false));`

You can also try to fire a click event on it if this isn't working.

Sorry that I can't test myself. At the moment I don't have a test phone or emulator.